Use icon as google maps marker in flutter
I know how to use a png image as image for a map marker:
static Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(
  {required String path, required int width}) async {
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
final ui.Codec codec = await ui
    .instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
final ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
final Uint8List bytes =
    (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
return bytes;

}
and then use the bytes with BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes).
How can I do the same with a pre-installed icon, such as Icons.camera_alt_outlined?
As a side question. In google maps we often see marker in a form of a pin with an icon in it. Is there out there a package that can achieve such a thing?
I know if I do it by myself I will have to get deep into canvas and other stuff. It is just a nice to have for my project.

Have you tried this yet? final customIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(12, 12)),         'assets/images/car-icon.png')

As I said in my question, it is about icons which are part of the material package. I don't have them stored somewhere as png file.

Please try this article. Hope it can help you!

You can refer to this discussion
